# What is this dashboard/windshield accessory on Columbo's car?

Tags: part-identification, peugeot, windshield, accessories, vintage

We know that Detective Lt. Columbo drove a [1959 Peugeot Convertible Model 403](https://www.cgiautomotive.com/what-car-did-columbo-drive/) - and in [this video](https://youtu.be/dLvumtMaYeE?t=458) you can see it in action.

I've cued the video to this image:

[image: odd dashboard accessory in Columbo's car]

What is that interesting "corrugated" wire metal device inside the windscreen?  It's a convertible, so maybe that's just the thing you use, when the top is down, to keep pigeons from landing on the dashboard and pooping on it.  (But probably not.)

Comment: Probably the front-of-the-dash clips to keep the front edge of a [tonneau cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MGA_DSC_4480.JPG) in place.

Comment: Could be, but if you scroll down [on this page](https://www.luxuo.com/cars/automobile/classic-car-1959-peugeot-403-convertible-for-sale-with-french-auction-house-ivoire-nimes.html) to the 4th photo its a clear interior shot of a 403 without such clips.

Comment: Perhaps a tonneau wasn't standard from the factory, but was an option, and so didn't appear on all 403 vehicles. Perhaps it was available aftermarket, and didn't appear on all 403 vehicles.

Comment: @davidbak - I'm thinking you're going to have to binge some Columbo episodes so you can see how he uses it :o) Peter Falk was a genius at this role! And of note ... he was actually blind in one eye! Never slowed him down.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - I considered that - wouldn't be surprised to discover he used it as a cigar holder ...

Comment: Whatever it is I doubt it came standard on the Peugeot. I've just gone traipsing through the internet looking at different 403's and his is the only one I found with it.

Answer (score 1):

This photo may explain why it was fitted if it is not standard -

[image]

I got the photo from this [website](http://www.columbo-site.freeuk.com/inside.htm).

Comment: Filing system for papers!  Yet, when pulled over, he can never access his police identification ("wrong pocket!").  That website is a good find, thank you!